# What's a good percentage/mix of used data, unallocated, and index space for a database

Tags: sql-server, best-practices, disk-space

When I look at the Disk Usage report for my database [`SQL SERVER`] I currently have about 50% used space, 20% unallocated, and 30% index. Is there a good ratio try and hit?

I know everything is situational, I'm wondering if people with experience have a range that makes them more comfortable or if there are some best practices available for this topic.

Is that too much indexing? Not enough unallocated space for growth?

Thanks.

[image: snapshot of my db disk usage]
Edit:
I appreciate all the edge cases of this is how it could be and there is definitely a case for every situation. Guess asking for best practices isn't a recommended best practice. We have a high volume of reads and writes to the database. - That may change the answers, and I know the responses will still be a snarky it depends, and I know that. Everything depends. Simply asking to understand if people have a feel good zone about things.

Comment: Completely subjective question.

Comment: Not entirely, I wouldn't think you would ever have 100% index, right? My point is there are some bounds to the problem, it's not 100% subjective.

Comment: Why would 100% index not be right? If it's a reporting system where read performance is critical, a ton of indexes might be right for the business. "It depends" and subjective.

Comment: How could you have no data and only indexes?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those "it depends" situations.

The only one that we can answer is for "unallocated". You want there to be free space inside the file so that it doesn't have to autogrow (if enabled).

As far as indexes, what you need for your system is dependent on your system. Whatever gives you good performance for reads and decent enough performance for writes might be what you need for your system. But what happens if the business has decided that reads are far more important than writes? Maybe for that system you need tons of indexes in order to satisfy the performance requirements of the business and the users. The more indexes you have on a table, the slower writes are going to be.

The answer: IT DEPENDS.

Comment: It Depends is the right answer.  :)

Comment: So having 100% data is fine? or 100% index is fine?

Comment: @markokstate, 100% data would indicate lack of indexes, which would likely be a performance problem. But what if all that's happening is inserts? Inserts would be fast. If that's what the business wants, then sure 100% data would be okay. So again, it's an "it depends" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each company has a different comfort level on allowable space.  This usually measured by growth of the data, importance of the application, size of the database and available money to buy storage space.

This is more of an opinion answer.  My opinion will vary depending on the factors above.

Assume a database size of 200 GB with a slow growth rate.  My preference is to have 50% available space.  I have my alerts set up to warn me at 25% space left, then at 15% and then Page at 5% as critical.

Your setup may be different.  If you have a highly transactional database that is large in size and eats up data storage like candy, then it will be a combination of maintenance and storage growth.  In a terabyte size database it is difficult to justify 500GB just sitting unused unless the growth rates or transaction bursts warrant it.

A lot of this is subjective until you put a case to the question.  Just percentages don't tell the whole story.

Hope that helps.